# Yemenite tea-like coffee?

Tags: bean-varieties

I was in Yemen a few years ago, and when ordering "Yemenite Coffee" there, one would get a cup with a liquid which tasted like coffee, but from the intensity, color and strength was more like tea.

I was told the coffee was made from the peelings of the coffee beans (because all the beans are determined for export).

Is it true that they brew their coffee with the peelings of roasted coffee beans? How exactly is this kind of coffee made? Does it have a special name? Are there similar kinds of drinks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you had [coffee cherry tea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_cherry_tea), also called *cascara*, and regionally other names; in Yemen it seems to be called *qishr* according to Wikipedia.

It's (to me) delicious, but rather different than roasted, brewed coffee beans. It has a lovely red hue, similar to [rooibos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooibos) but lighter.

It's made by infusing the dried coffee cherries or just the husks (as you described in the question). It is steeped like an herbal tea, in hot water just off the boil. [This article](http://www.benttreecoffee.com/allcoffees/cascara-coffee-cherry-tea) says that it can be brewed using cold-brew techniques also. I've only had it cold/iced or lukewarm, but it is probably lovely hot also.

Comment: @Bob -- btw, [here's a later answer of mine](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/1937/262) that discusses the taste and availability (and a picture!) of the coffee cherry skin and pulp.

Answer (score 1):

Yemenite white coffee consists of:

1. lightly roasted beans.
2. Hawaij spices mixture (Cardamon, Cloves, cinnamon, ginger root and nutmeg).[image][image]