# What variety of coffee berries are good for jam?

Tags: beans, coffee-berries

Some people make jam out of coffee fruits, and I would like to try that out. It seems difficult, as it requires getting actual fruits, and as fresh as possible---probably even harder out of the Green Belt.

What variety of coffee should I order?

---

A bit of background: The jam idea comes from reading a story around the 2014 barista selection to represent the U.S. One contender partnered with a Venezuelan coffee farmer, whose mother was making traditional jam with coffee. That's how I got into searching more.

Comment: I've had [coffee jelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_jelly), prepared with coffee and agar or gelatine; but that's more like roasted/brewed coffee. Sounds like you are interested in retaining the whole cherry (like a [preserve/conserve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_preserves#Conserve)) -- would you consider green (unroasted) beans, or just coffee cherry husks? Might be easier to acquire/use. +1 for interesting idea.

Comment: Early stage with jam actually. I believe the fruit is necessary---the cherry husk. The conserve is a great idea to start with, actually! I'm thinking about peaberries for their sweetness, but they are pricey.

Comment: I let aside jelly for other questions! Gelatins and agar were great, especially due to cultural and diet issues, but I'd prefer with discuss that on another question ;-)

Comment: I think that *using dried husks only* would be a good start. I posit that husks will be easier to obtain, cheaper, and (if they're dried) will ship better. And you could try to make [*cascara*](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/454/262) also :). Once/if you find the cherry/beans/husks, consider asking about process over at [cooking.se]; credit to @Jefromi for suggesting this. You might consider to pose the "anybody make coffee cherry preserves" there anyway (or I could, if you don't want yet-another SE profile, or if you don't mind).

Comment: Maybe modifying this to ask about the factors that make a bean good for jam (and recommendations of beans which have those properties) would make this less likely to be closed as opinion based?

Answer (score 4):

After much chatter about this question, I must admit that I've become a little obsessed with this concept. Maybe a *lot* obsessed...

**Concept.**  I see three other possible ways of making a [jam/conserve/preserve/marmalade/jelly/...](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/451/262) out of *coffee fruit* (i.e., coffee berries / coffee cherries) or *coffee cherry husks* (by "husks" I mean basically the fruit with seeds removed -- everything *except* the beans), in decreasing order of actual coffee fruit content:

- Use the whole fruit (possibly with seeds and all), so as to make a [conserve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_preserves#Conserve);
- Make something like a [jam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_preserves#Jam) or marmalade, using the shredded, dried, rehydrated husks;
- Infuse the husks as [cascara](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/451/262), discard the spent husks, then make a [jelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_preserves#Jelly) out of the resulting brew (tisane).

**Exclusions.** Note that I am *not* including [coffee jelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_jelly), which is made of (conventional, roasted) brewed coffee, as noted previously; also *not* including making a jam out of roasted or un-roasted coffee *beans* themselves. Both of those are interesting concepts, but discounted here to be left as separate topics.

**Progress!** I searched a bunch for a source of *any* coffee cherries or dried husks. Amazon didn't even seem to sell any (must have been my error!?). I asked around at a few local coffee shops, with little progress. I found a few pages, [like this one](http://blog.kathrynmcgowan.com/tag/dried-coffee-cherries/) and one from [a NYT blog](http://tmagazine.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/11/11/grass-fed-pop-some-coffee-cherries) that gave a glimmer of hope that husks (at least) could be found. Both of those articles point to [Counter Culture Coffee](https://counterculturecoffee.com) as selling these, but they're not in stock. An immensely helpful person from CCC pointed me to [Verve Coffee Roasters, who sell coffee cherry husks for cascara](http://www.vervecoffeeroasters.com/collections/coffee/products/cascara-coffee-cherry-tea). So as to get my lot before the rush on coffee cherry husks that would undoubtedly come from this post, I ordered some. Since I'm having trouble being patient and waiting for the stuff to arrive, I started...

**Seeking Seasoned Advice!** With all due credit to OP @EricPlaton, I posted a question over at [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) about the concept of [making jam or preserves out of coffee cherry husks or whole coffee cherries](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/54942/25286). I wrote a comment about this above, but I still hope OP doesn't mind!

More to come, and any comments or suggestions are kindly welcomed.

Comment: Please go ahead! Answers matter :-)

Comment: Side note: there's a helpful [botanical diagram of the coffee bean at wikia](http://coffee.wikia.com/wiki/Coffee_bean).