# Coffee with colors?

Tags: beans, bean-varieties, green-coffee, coffee-berries

I've heard some types of coffee have blue color (after brewing), does anyone know the name of it? Also is there any coffee that have color other than brown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the best of my knowledge, no.

There is a bean variety named Jamaican Blue Mountain. Maybe its name could make people misunderstood... Nothing that is blue I've heard of.

Other than that, not the regular coffee as we know it, but some of its variations may have different colors.

- **Green coffee:** This is the coffee brewed from the unroasted coffee beans. This looks pale yellowish/green. Its taste is more close to tea than coffee.

You may check the [green-coffee](/questions/tagged/green-coffee) tag on [Coffee SE](https://coffee.stackexchange.com) for further information on that.

[image: green coffee]

- **Coffee cherry tea (aka Cascara or Sultana in Bolivia):** This is the tea made from the dried coffee cherries. Its color is pale red when brewed. It tastes like raisins or raspberries.

A previous discussion on this is made in [What does a coffee cherry taste like?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1936/what-does-a-coffee-cherry-taste-like/1937#1937) question on [Coffee SE](https://coffee.stackexchange.com).

Also, the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_cherry_tea) may be helpful.

[image: cascara]

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of [white espresso before](http://www.phoenixnewtimes.com/restaurants/white-espresso-at-thirdspaces-grind-house-coffee-is-a-strange-take-on-a-classic-6535304).It's basically any bean that is severely under roasted.Just long enough to take out some of the grass and bitter notes.

It's not actually white though, it looks more pale and kinda greenish to me.